# SVG scalability with number of elements

Tags: canvas, svg, bigdata

I'm having a bit of an issue regarding a visualization that I need to implement. It's a 2D matrice that until now had 100 x 100 maximum size. This was done with HTML + javascript until now. We also needed to be able to manipulate data, with events on one element and events on one row that would edit data, then refresh the table and so on.

Now the problem is this needs to scale up to 1000 x 1000 elements. I tried doing a svg based visualization, with 'rect' elements for each matrix entry (so events on each rect, and css classes are still available). However it seems to take such a long time that browser just breaks down.

So question would be: can this be done with SVG? So 1000 x 1000 elements with events, zoom or panning while keeping the response time at least decent. Otherwise besides canvas are there any other alternatives that can offer event handling (and optionally styles) a bit easier to do?

All the best

Comment: Are you sure, that you really need a million items at the same time? No paging etc possible?

Comment: You could delegate all events and just have a couple of event listeners in your document or window, but even then 1 million elements would slow the browser to a crawl. Go with canvas.

Comment: Use tiling method, only 100x100 element would appear at any given time. The rest is kept in browser's memory. A few other [alternatives](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/05/02/data-visualization-with-web-standards/)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yeah all the items need to be seen at the same time. Guess canvas is the only doable solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performance of RaphaelJS with thousands of paths/rectangles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394351/performance-of-raphaeljs-with-thousands-of-paths-rectangles)